# Real Number recursion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recursion

Let $T_{n}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $T_{n+1}\ge T_{n}^{2}+\frac{1}{5}$
Prove that $\sqrt{T_{n+5}}\ge T_{n}$.
I rearranged the first expression in terms of $T_{n}$, but seemingly to no avail. Are there any other pointers for solving this problem?

Answer (score 3):

For all real $x$ we have
$$
x^2-x
=
\Bigl(x-{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\Bigr)^2
-
{\small{\frac{1}{4}}}
\ge
-{\small{\frac{1}{4}}}
$$
so then we get
\begin{align*}
T_{n+5}
&=
T_{n+1}
+
\sum_{k=1}^4
(T_{n+k+1}-T_{n+k})
\\[4pt]
&\ge
T_{n+1}
+
\sum_{k=1}^4
\left(\Bigl(T_{n+k}^2+{\small{\frac{1}{5}}}\Bigr)-T_{n+k}\right)
\\[4pt]
&=
T_{n+1}
+
\sum_{k=1}^4
\left(\Bigl(T_{n+k}^2-T_{n+k}\Bigr)+{\small{\frac{1}{5}}}\right)
\\[4pt]
&\ge
T_{n+1}
+
\sum_{k=1}^4
\Bigl(-{\small{\frac{1}{4}}}+{\small{\frac{1}{5}}}\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=
T_{n+1}
+
\sum_{k=1}^4
\Bigl(-{\small{\frac{1}{20}}}\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=
T_{n+1}
-
{\small{\frac{1}{5}}}
\\[4pt]
&\ge
\Bigl(T_n^2+{\small{\frac{1}{5}}}\Bigr)
-
{\small{\frac{1}{5}}}
\\[4pt]
&=
T_n^2
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $\sqrt{T_{n+5}}\ge T_n$.

Comment: how did you know to start with that proposition (for all real x)?

Comment: @LÜHECCHEgon: It's use appears later as we develop the recursive inequality, so I put it first so as not to interrupt the logical flow.